# Method onValidate not working on IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fine-uploader

I am using a custom onValidate method with FineUploader that is working in every browser but IE9. The method is something like this:

```
onValidate: function (fileOrBlobData) {
    var validExtension = false;
    var validExtensions = ["jpg","png"];
    var fileName = fileOrBlobData.name || '';
    for (i=0; i<validExtensions.length && !validExtension; i++) {
        var extRegex = new RegExp('\\.' + validExtensions[i] + '$', 'i');
        if (fileName.match(extRegex) != null) {
            validExtension = true;
        }
        if (!validExtension) {
            alert('Unsupported file type. Please try again.');
            return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
}
```

The difference is that in IE10, for example, the fileOrBlobData is an object File (seen with an alert) and in IE9 is an object HTMLInputElement.

Why this difference? How can I assure that this is going to work in IE9?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Fine Uploader are you using?  This sounds like a bug I fixed in 3.9.0-3.

Comment: 3.7.0. Should we update?

Comment: If you'd like to fix this issue, yes.  It is fixed in the latest release: 3.9.0-3.

Comment: Thanks Ray, will update it and test. I also tested to assign fileOrBlobData = $_FILES['qqfile']; when browser was IE9 and it seems it worked, but if it is an issue an update will be better. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue in the parameter passed to the `validate` event handlers.  This issue affected all browsers, but was only noticeable in older browsers, such as IE9.  Newer browsers that support the File API were shielded from this issue for the most part due to the fact that the `File` object was mistakenly passed to the `validate` event handler, but the `File` object's properties match the expected properties of the data parameter object passed to the event handler.  You can read more about this in [issue #993 is the Fine Uploader Github issue tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/993).

This was fixed in the latest release of Fine Uploader: 3.9.0-3.